# github actions error when running cypress tests

Tags: reactjs, cypress, github-actions

I am getting the following error in github actions for cypress,

[Cypress logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G0Lm.png)

This is app's package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.12.13",
        "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.12",
        "@cypress/instrument-cra": "^1.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^5.7.0",
        "cypress": "7.6.0",
        "cypress-dark": "^1.7.14",
        "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.7",
        "cypress-movie": "^3.0.20",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint": "7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.14.0",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.6.5",
        "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0"
    },
```

The confusing part is in the package.json it is cypress 7.6.0 but in github actions CI logs it says 9.5.1.

Any idea what the issue is?

workflow,
https://gist.github.com/bonyfusbouvet/9c264f0fa03170744275131154de5c4a

Comment: Plaese share GitHub/ workflow .yml file

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bonyfusbouvet/9c264f0fa03170744275131154de5c4a

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider `package-lock.json` file as ignore file, then it may be a reason to try to install Cypress latest.

Comment: No I dont consider as ignore file. Tried the latest version still get the error.